# Creating multiple threads and invoking other exectuables in Cygwin through system()?

Tags: c, cygwin, pthreads, executable

I am working on a project in Cygwin. In an attempt to create multiple threads in C, and each thread calls another executable through the command line using the system() function, it turns out things are not working properly. Specifically, the code I have is like this:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_THREADS     5

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
  long tid;
  tid = (long)threadid;
  system("date ");
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
  int rc;
  long t;

  for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
    printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
    if (rc){
       printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
       exit(-1);
    }
  }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

But it does not work. The error I get is segmenetation fault with stack overflows. Anyway has an idea on how to call other executables in the system shell in parallel by creating multiple threads? 
Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing obvious wrong with the code and it runs fine on linux.  As a shot in the dark, did you link with -pthreads, -lpthreads, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Add this code :

```
for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
  pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
}
```

before

```
pthread_exit(NULL);
```

as called in `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

Several bugs here:

1. In the main() function, after you create the thread, you should use pthread_exit() to exit from all the individual thread.   So exit() use is not right here.
2. In the end of the main() function, just before you terminate the main thread, call pthread_join() to wait for all the individual thread to terminate.
3. At the end after all the child threads have terminated, you can call exit() to terminate the process itself.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/terminate-c-thread/

Answer (score 0):

That issue looks worth reporting to the Cygwin mailing list.

What you can do instead is to do away with threads and use [fork()/exec()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork-exec) or [spawn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spawn_%28computing%29)(_P_NOWAITO, ...) to create the child processes.

(spawn() actually is a family of functions; see [/usr/include/process.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process.h) for details. Its use is recommended as it avoids Cygwin's high fork overhead.)